# Draw an helix and a circle under it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw something like this:[image]

I found something similar, but I don't know how to draw a circle and the orange intervals under it such that I can color it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
 view={-20}{-20},
 axis line style = ultra thick,
 axis lines=middle,
 zmax=80,
  xmax=2,
   ymax=2,
 height=12cm,
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 ztick=\empty,
 clip=false,
 x label style={at={(axis cs:2,0.051)},anchor=north},
   xlabel={$y$},
 y label style={at={(axis cs:0.05,2)},anchor=north},
   ylabel={$x$},
 z label style={at={(axis cs:0.075,0,80)},anchor=north},
   zlabel={$z$},
]
\addplot3+[domain=0:11*pi,samples=500,samples y=0,black,no marks,ultra         thick] 
({sin(deg(x))}, 
{cos(deg(x))}, 
{6*x/(pi)})
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please some help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were already close. Adding the circle is as simple as

```
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
```

For the orange marks one can employ `decorations.markings`. For your convenience I added a style, and for repeated use one can use the `/.list` key.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrmark/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position #1/11-0.1/11 with {\arrow[orange]{<};},
mark=at position #1/11+0.1/11 with {\arrow[orange]{>};}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
 view={-20}{-20},
 axis line style = ultra thick,
 axis lines=middle,
 zmax=80,
  xmax=2,
   ymax=2,
 height=12cm,
 xtick=\empty,
 ytick=\empty,
 ztick=\empty,
 clip=false,
 x label style={at={(axis cs:2,0.051)},anchor=north},
   xlabel={$y$},
 y label style={at={(axis cs:0.05,2)},anchor=north},
   ylabel={$x$},
 z label style={at={(axis cs:0.075,0,80)},anchor=north},
   zlabel={$z$},
]
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\addplot3+[domain=0:11*pi,samples=500,samples y=0,black,no marks,ultra thick,
arrmark/.list={0.6,2.6,4.6,6.6,8.6,10.6}] 
({sin(deg(x))}, 
{cos(deg(x))}, 
{6*x/(pi)})
node [circle,scale=0.5,fill,pos=0]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]